# Exception Handling in MVC using HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I want to implement Exception Handling in my MVC project using the custom error attribute.

The 4th example provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine#Method4:-Inheritingfrom%E2%80%9CHandleErrorAttribute%E2%80%9D) is incomplete in terms of where we should enter view name, a controller name, etc and how to decorate the controllers and action with the new attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom error attribute as such

```
public class MyCustomErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
       public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            //Do something with the Controller or Action, e.g. Logging the exception
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Then add the following code into the `Global.asax.cs`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(MyCustomErrorAttribute);
}
```

Then simply use the attribute on the controller level as such

```
[MyCustomErrorAttribute]
public class HomeController: Controller
{

}
```

or on the action method level as such

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    [MyCustomErrorAttribute]
    public ActionResult Index(){

    }
}
```